# Upload video on cloudflare using TUSKit with swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, cloudflare

I am trying to upload the video to [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) with TUSKit recommended [here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/guidelines-to-upload-stream-with-swift/191173) ...

Video is uploaded in `POST` request `form-data`  against the key `file` ... but the read the docs of [TUSClient](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TUSKit) it doesn't offer the `POST` request with `form-data` ...

here is the upload method of TUSKit ...

```
 @discardableResult
    public func upload(data: Data, preferredFileExtension: String? = nil, uploadURL: URL? = nil, customHeaders: [String: String] = [:], context: [String: String]? = nil) throws -> UUID
```

how i am supposed to send the video in `form-data` or do I need to switch to [Alamofire](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Alamofire) ??